# Change JRE in a NetBeans project

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I have a NetBeans project which is using the JRE 1.4 environment which means I can't use generics.

How can I change the project to use 1.6(?), so I can use generics?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- In the *Project* tab, right-click on the project and select *Properties*. In the *Library* category select *Java Platform JDK 1.6*.
- Then, in the *Source* category select *Source/Binary Format JDK6*.
- This assumes that you installed JDK 1.6 and NetBeans knows about
  this.
- JDK 1.6 must be known to NetBeans as a Java Platform.
- From the menu select menu *Tools* → *Java Platform Manager*.
- If *JDK 1.6* is not in the list, you can add it there.

Answer (score 1):

In NetBeans 8.2,

- right click the project, and select *Properties*
- under the menu build/compile, select the Java platform from the drop down menu

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in NetBeans 8.0.2

When undertaking the steps in [OliBlogger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128256/change-jre-in-a-netbeans-project/4142528#4142528) in changing JRE or JDK for a project, NetBeans attempts to save the project with the new JDK (9 in this instance), but it goes into an infinite loop and eventually gives an OutOfMemoryError:

[image: Infinite loop while saving new project with new JDK]

[image: OutOfMemoryError]