# Java project was running, but when I'm trying to build it I have NullPointerException at startsWith (NetBeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I have a next problem. When I'm running project from NetBeans IDE evrything is fine. But when I'm trying to build the project I have exception:

```
Compiling 2 source files to D:\JAVA\Projects\streamer\build\classes
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.7.0-ea). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.startsWith(String.java:1433)
    at java.lang.String.startsWith(String.java:1462)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.SymbolArchive.addZipEntry(SymbolArchive.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.ZipArchive.<init>(ZipArchive.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.SymbolArchive.<init>(SymbolArchive.java:41)
............
D:\JAVA\Projects\streamer\nbproject\build-impl.xml:603: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\JAVA\Projects\streamer\nbproject\build-impl.xml:245: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I'm not use String.startsWith method, but I'm use String.indexOf in one place:

```
int lastIndex = nodeName.indexOf("date",0);
if (lastIndex != -1 || nodeName.equals("birthday")) {
    txt_val = getHash(txt_val,Boolean.TRUE);
} else {
    txt_val = getHash(txt_val,Boolean.FALSE);
}
```

nodeName is not null. And I couldn't understand where is an error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use Java 7 intentionally? Try Java 6 - it should be more stable. Look here [Change JRE in NetBeans project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128256/change-jre-in-netbeans-project)

Comment: I'm not JAVA programmer initially and I thought, that I must read some books about it for further programming :)

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128256/change-jre-in-netbeans-project

Comment: All done
Only two notes with JRE 1.6:

AppNormaliser.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Answer (score 0):

Error is in compiler like the exception sayes. Why are you using java 1.7?

Comment: Because it was installed on my workstation.
I would try to use java 1.6 and wrote what would be happend.