# How to specify which JRE to use in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, java

I have two JRE in my system. One is 32-bit and the other one 64-bit. In Eclipse I can configure both and choose which one to use when running my application.

I'm wondering if I can do the same thing in Netbeans. I've tried to go to Project Properties, Libraries and then tried to configure a new JRE there, through Manage Platforms, but it doesn't accept the directory of my JRE. How should I proceed?

Be aware that I'm talking about JRE, and not JDK ;)

EDIT: I managed to make it work by downloading a new 32-bit JDK and selecting its directory. I still couldn't make it accept a JRE directory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128256/change-jre-in-netbeans-project look here. I knows this is a solution for JDK, but clearly the question is for JRE, so I dunno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not you can run Netbeans with just the JRE depends on what bundle you have downloaded. In [Netbeans 7](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/70/relnotes.html) only C/C++ and PHP bundles can be run with the JRE.

Older versions of Netbeans include more languages under this JRE umbrella, but the principle is the same.

The JDK contains the JRE *plus* tools to debug and compile code, so if you're doing anything Java based apart from just running the IDE, netbeans depends on the JDK.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.This question asks how to specify what JRE to use to run Netbeans, not how to develop in Java nor what version of Netbeans you can use just the JRE rather than SDK.