# Setting JRE in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, java

I have JDK 1.6, JRE6 and JRE7 (64-bit & 32-bit) installed in my PC.

I am using Netbeans 7.3 BETA 2 and it is using JDK 6 and JRE 6.

I want to change it to JRE7. How can i achieve this ?

I have checked in Stackoverflow itself and found that we have to change the netbeans.conf file content for the netbeans_jdkhome value to the path of new Java path.

In another stackoverflow question, I found [How to specify which JRE to use in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195932/how-to-specify-which-jre-to-use-in-netbeans).

But, in this also, I am not able to find how to get this resolved. Can anybody help on this ?

My installation path is as follows,

JDK6 path - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_31

JRE6 path - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6

JRE7 path - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7 (32-bit)

JRE7 path - C:\Program Files\Java\jre7 (64-bit)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All you need Jdk for netbeans.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Goto Tools -> Platforms

[image]

Click "Add Platform", browse to the location where the JDK you want to add is installed....

[image]

Click on the JDK you want to add and select "Finish"

**Updating projects**

You can change the platform that projects use, by right clicking the project node and selecting properties and selecting `Libraries`.  Here you change the platform that the project will use to build the classes with.

[image]

You can also change the source/binary format (version) which Netbeans is expecting to use.  For example, you use JDK 7, but build/develop for Java 6

[image]

**Changing the JDK that Netbeans itself uses to run**

Goto `{install/location/of/Netbeans}/etc` and open the `netbeans.conf`.

There is a property called `netbeans_jdkhome` (it was towards the end of my file).  You change this to what ever JDK you want Netbeans to be launched with

Comment: So, Can't I add JRE alone ? So, Do I required to install JDK 7 separately ?

Comment: @Dinesh No, you can't just tell Netbeans to use a specific JRE, it only works with JDKs

Comment: @johnchen902 I use to have JDK 3, 4 & 5!

Comment: @MadProgrammer It depends on the NetBeans bundle. The PHP variant for instance can be run with the JRE and without the JDK. Then, however, you must configure it via `netbeans.conf` because `Tools -> Platforms` is not available.

Comment: @twigmac I wouldn't say that was the question

Comment: @MadProgrammer I wasn't so much referring to the question itself but rather to [your answer to Dinesh's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610167/setting-jre-in-netbeans/17610225#comment25632613_17610225). With some NetBeans bundles you can do just that: tell Netbeans to use a specific JRE (not JDK) and it works. In addition, the question hasn't been explicitly asked for a Java NetBeans bundle, so folks using HTML/PHP/C/C++ bundles are led here, too.

Comment: @twigmac Then we're talking about two different things :P