# Can I set the default JDK in Netbeans config file as the default?

Tags: java, netbeans, config

Whenever I update my jdk and try to open Netbeans, I get the message that the folder for the previous version of the jdk cannot be found, do I want to use the default?

I always click yes, and have no issues. I have found answers on how to update the config file to open the new jdk that I updated, but I would like to know if it's possible to make that "default" the default in the config file, if that makes sense. No matter what I update for the jdk, Netbeans knows that is the default. I want to somehow set that as the primary opening folder so when I update the jdk, it auto opens the newest one.

First time posting. Forgive me if this question is ignorant.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610167/setting-jre-in-netbeans/17610225#17610225) provides instructions (towards the end) on how to change the JDK/JRE that Netbeans itself uses when it is run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting JRE in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610167/setting-jre-in-netbeans)