# How to solve message running in simulator codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

Please help me to solve this issue to use hot reload in simulator.

[image]

my JAVA_HOME is  not pointing to this path. Where can I set this in simulator?
not pointing to this path. Where can I set this in simulator?

Comment: I'm using netbeans 15 and JDK 8

Answer (score 0):

The IDE settings for maven are different from the ones in the system. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17610225/756809

Make sure the right JDK is used. Also check the build settings globally for maven and make sure the right JDK is set there. Make sure the project itself has the right JDK set on it.