# My java project build in jdk 7 . I want to convert it into jdk 6. How can I do this?

Tags: netbeans, java

My java project build in jdk 7 . I want to convert it into jdk 6. How can I do this?
It is possible that convert it?
in netbeans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add separate JDK (1.6) to your IDE preferences. In build path of project change used JRE Environment from 1.7 to just added 1.6.

**UPD:**

For NetBeans click `Tools > Java Platforms > Add Platform` where you specify additional JRE.
Then go to your `Project view > Right Click on libraries > Properties` and select just added java platform.

Comment: I installed jdk 1,6 but I cant find where I change it in preferences? I use netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your NetBeans project source code and binary output to be Java 6, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4142528/303598):

> In the Project tab, right click on the project and select Properties. In the Library category select Java Platform JDK 1.6. Then, in the Source category select Source/Binary Format JDK6.

Note, you don't have to since JDK 7 is backward compatible.

Alternatively, if it is a Maven based project, you can configure the [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) to use version 1.6:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```