# tomcat7 log keep repeating same error

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to run javaee maven project using tomcat7. My problem is when I run project I get continuously running tomcat error log. I deleted all catalina logs in 
 C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\logs folder. 

Now there is only today log and it doesn't show any errors. 

I tried to add error log of tomcat log in netbeans. It is pretty large. This is the one repeating. This is an old error.

```
 Aug 03, 2015 12:36:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet index threw exception
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 16

13:             
14:     </head>
15:     <body>
16:         <jsp:include page="layout"></jsp:include>
17:         <div id="wrapper">   
18:         <div id="page-wrapper">
19:             <div class="container-fluid">


Stacktrace:
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at 
ect...
```

There are tons of error generating right now. please help me for god sake. This thing is driving me crazy. 

Ps: There is a stackoverflow error too.

Comment: have you used jstl lib(for <jsp:include page> tag) in your jsp?

Comment: Is there something like "Caused by: " in the StackTrace? Plz post the full Error Message.

Comment: I use jstl for some other operations. but not include. @AnkurMahajan

Comment: could it be something with the java runtime settings you are using in your eclipse project? For example that you use jdk 1.7 but for this project you need 1.4 or 1.5 compliant version of the facet? what happens if you chabnge java compiler path in project settings to some earlier versions of jdk?

Comment: @hinneLinks there is no caused by or caused

Comment: @aviad unfortunately this is a netbeans project

Comment: sorry for the wrong guess of IDE! does netbeans have a similar configs? (kind of rhetoric question...)

Comment: :( tell me what is it. and I'll try to find

Comment: There must be a cause of the JasperException, the Method handleJspException is called with a seperate cause exception. Maybe its called "root cause" - some second Exception should be after the lines you posted.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/4142528/579580

Comment: `<jsp:include page="layout">` *layout* what? jsp? html? something?

Comment: jsp page. I mapped it in web.xml.

Comment: @hinneLinks I'm happy to say Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.io.FileNotFoundException: The requested resource (/EMS/layout) is not available gives toot ccause

Comment: So, is there a folder "EMS" with a File "layout" somewhere in your app?

Comment: Actually guys I figure out the error. My jsp mapping was wrong. And I fixed it. But problem is there are tons of old tomcat errors are loading now. How to stop it? Plz help me @hinneLinks

Comment: Stop the errors by fixing them. If they not related to this Question, post a new Question. Otherweise edit your Question.

Comment: Now there are no errors. But project is not running. :9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was jsp class mapping error. I found it from Apache tomcat log in netbeans by searching "root cause". Thank you **hinneLinks** for that. I guess stackoverflow error was happened because every time I run project this mapping error occurred. ***I hope someone will explain to me why stackoverflow error occurred and why error log started repeating***. Thank you everybody for your support.