# cannot find symbol java.awt and java.util

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

i'm using NB.the ide gives error that it cannot find symbol java.awt . tried running the same code in eclipse.it also gives same error. it gives the error cannot find symbol even on creation of new JFrame.

An error:

[image]

Comment: Try set JDK for project. This link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128256/change-jre-in-netbeans-project

Comment: @AlexChermenin i have tried the above solution but it still gives the same error

Comment: do you by any chance have a class or field called `java`?

Comment: @ThomasKläger yes i have a class named java....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class named `java` obscures the package name `java`, see [Java Language Specification 6.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls6.html#jls-6.4.2):

> A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be interpreted as the name of a variable, a type, or a package. In these situations, the rules of §6.5 specify that a variable will be chosen in preference to a type, and that a type will be chosen in preference to a package. Thus, it is may sometimes be impossible to refer to a visible type or package declaration via its simple name. We say that such a declaration is obscured.

That means that within the package that contains the class `java` you will not be able to reference to classes from any of the `java.*` packages through qualified names.

However you could still import the classes you need and reference them by simple names:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

// within some method:
    Logger.getLogger(....);
```